# Why doesn't the PropertyGrid raise Keyboard/Mouse events?

Tags: c#, winforms

Why does this never get called ?

```
        propertyGrid.KeyDown += new KeyEventHandler(propertyGrid_KeyDown);

        private void propertyGrid_KeyDown(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
        {
           PoorLittleMethod(); //Never gets called
        }
```

This seems to be the same for Mouse event

I'veread on some forums that PGrid is tricky on raising such events as it Inherits them from Control but does not really Raise them. is that true ? If yes, how to bypass that ?

*EDIT 1:* 
*As this seems to be "regular", I find it very light from MS not to specify this explicitely on the MSDN Reference of the propertyGrid class and leave events "as is" as if they were usable, whereas they are not. Tricky things like these are at least usually specified in "notes" inside the refs.*

*EDIT 2:* 
I am presently coding a workaround. I'll be posting it soon.

Comment: Re your edit: the most peculiar thing is that MSDN actually has a `PropertyGrid.KeyDown` event _example_ on the reference page with _example code_.

Comment: Well in this case, I did really miss something, because, that code, as is, never get called in my case when I try to reproduce it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `PropertyGrid`'s `KeyDown` property is marked as `Browsable(false)` - presumably the conclusion we can take from this is that it is not supported in an of itself but is in fact present as a side-effect of its inheritance hierarchy.

Though, interestingly enough, its `EditorBrowsable` attribute (which is also a designer indicator, for Intellisense and the suchlike) is set as `EditorBrowsableState.Advanced` - where we would expect `EditorBrowsableState.Never` should the former presumption be true.

Some information from [MSDN](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/vbgeneral/thread/9d6b10b4-abf5-4c26-ad0e-c2a038b4a2f1/) forums outlines the *why* of this situation:

*From the tool [UI Spy](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms727247.aspx) we can see the PropertyGrid is a just a panel and it consists of three Windows Controls. Our KeyDown event should be processed by the child control table.
The structure:*

```
-"pane" "PropertyGrid"
  --"pane" "Description Pane"
  --"table" "Properties Window"
  --"tool bar" "ToolBar"
```

The suggested solution (also provided in the MSDN link) to overcoming this is to use native system calls to retrieve window/control information, subclass `NativeWindow` and override the `WndProc` method to handle the events you like, `KeyDown` in this case.

Comment: Well... That's Freakin'weird and upsetting. I mean, we're in 2010, this looks like old COM legacy :-(

Comment: This is not "freaking weird" and has nothing to do with COM, it's just how Windows input works! The input always goes to the control that has focus. Period. Now since PropertyGrid is a compound control and has all those TextBoxes&Comboboxes for editing values, what kind of KeyDown events do you want to receive? All of them? In that case override ProcessKeyPreview of the PropertyGrid and do your logic.

Comment: I wanted for example to change the default "Enter" Key behavior to exit the PBox (Among others ). Ok so I understand : The KeyEvents are captured by textboxes and controls before possibly being accessed by the PGrid control. But still, this is not convenient at all and the workaround is tedious (IMHO)

Answer (score -1):

You can **override** this from subclass of `PropertyGrid` to get some key info from windows message

```
protected override bool ProcessCmdKey(ref Message msg, Keys keyData)
```

Answer (score -2):

CSharp PropertyGrid Events

```
// Property grid events can’t be easily subscribed to however there is way to get at the KeyUp event without impacting operation. 
// Note: The KeyDown event can be subscribed to in the same manner but the propertygrid is NOT updated with the key presses. 
// This code is added in hope it may help someone else solve the problem. It is not offered as a total solution.

// First define a class variable to indicate that events have been added.
private bool m_bPropertyGridEventsAdded = false;

public GlassInfoEntryPage(ViewBase view)
        : base(view)
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        // Subscribe to SelectedGridItemChanged
        m_PropertyGrid.SelectedGridItemChanged += M_PropertyGrid_SelectedGridItemChanged;
    }

// Now define a SelectedGridItemChanged Event Handler
private void M_PropertyGrid_SelectedGridItemChanged(object sender, SelectedGridItemChangedEventArgs e)
{
        int nXlocation;
        int nYlocation;

        PropertyGrid oPropertyGrid;
        Control oControl;

        if (m_bPropertyGridEventsAdded == false)
        {
            oPropertyGrid = (PropertyGrid)sender;

            // Search the Property Grid for a PropertyGridView Control so events can be added to it
            for (nXlocation = 0; nXlocation < oPropertyGrid.Width; nXlocation += 10)
            {
                for (nYlocation = 0; nYlocation < oPropertyGrid.Height; nYlocation += 10)
                {
                    oControl = m_glassInfoPropertyGrid.GetChildAtPoint(new Point(nXlocation, nYlocation));

                    if (oControl != null)
                    {
                        if (oControl.GetType().ToString() == "System.Windows.Forms.PropertyGridInternal.PropertyGridView")
                        {
                            // Add Events here
                            oControl.Controls[1].KeyUp += MyCode_KeyUp;
                            m_bPropertyGridEventsAdded = true;
                            break;
                        }
                    }
                }

                if (m_bPropertyGridEventsAdded == true)
                {
                    break;
                }
            }
        }
    }        

// Handle the events
private void MyCode_KeyUp(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
{
}
```